# update max_intervals and interval Dash

Tags: python, setinterval, plotly-dash

I have a Dash project which read and plot data from a db in real-time.
I have tried to write a chained callback to control max_intervals and interval to enable the user to define both of them as input number! I have tried to define both as global variable to change them, but it does not work either!
any help is appreciated

my code:

```
waiting_time  = 1000   #witing time for interval dash 
max_time = 100 #100 defaulit 

app.layout = html.Div([  ... dcc.Interval(id='update_Graph', interval = waiting_time  , max_intervals = max_time),
dcc.Input(id = 'max_interval' , type="number", min=10, max=10000, step=50 , ),  ... ])

@app.callback(Output('update_Graph' , 'n_intervals'), 
             Input('max_interval' , 'value'), 
             )

def update_maxtime(value):
    global max_time
    max_time = value
```